# how do I change the url based on a theme?

Tags: 7, theming, uri

On some occasions, I've seen Drupal able to detect things like language and rewrite the url accordingly, so your actual displayed url reflects the detected value (like from http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar to http://www.mysite.com/en/foo/bar)

I want to do that based on the $theme_key. I want all the data, when displayed in the 'fancytheme' theme, rewritten from  http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar to http://fancytheme.mysite.com/foo/bar

- is that possible ?
- how would i go about ?
- is there a module out there that already does that ?

Comment: It sounds like you are already using the theme_key module - you want the url to switch only when its switched to the different theme, correct?

Comment: exactly - yes i'm using themekey. i didnt find a way to do it with that module, is there ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally, you could accomplish this with URL rewrite rules or theme switching modules like ThemeKey but you're moving to a different sub-domain which Drupal is going to assume is a new database. The best way to do this then is to use the [Domain Access module](http://drupal.org/project/domain) to simulate the use of a sub-domain without switching your database.

Domain Access is a little trickier to setup (read the install file carefully) but it allows separate themes for each subdomain with the "Domain Theme" module.

> Domain Theme -- Allows separate themes, theme settings and colors for
>   each subdomain.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion .. not sure if I understand the answer. I dont want to change the theme based on the url, i want to change the url based on the theme. how would you 'normally' accomplish this with ThemeKey ? URL rewrites are fine too, but how would apache know what theme i'm going to be in ?

Comment: right - but the url you are changing it to is a subdomain which will be interpreted by top-level drupal handling to look for a new database or sites folder. If you don't want to use a subdomain url (ex. mynewurl.samesite.com) but could use a same domain URL (ex. www.samesite.com/mynewurl) than you can easily do what you're asking in ThemeKey or Context, or any other theme switcher. If you want to use a subdomain, you want domain access because it interrupts the domain handling functionality before it triggers based on your rules.

Comment: ok .. suppose I dont use a subdomain, but a subdir, how would I do it using themekey ? so f.e. http://www.mysite.com/foo/bar gets rewritten to http://www.mysite.com/fancy/foo/bar ? do note, the original url *is* /foo/bar, it gets the fancy theme from, for example, a tag attached to the node